# Restart current instance using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm, child-process

I'd like to restart my application inside this application using NodeJS and NPM.

It doesn't work with `child_process` :

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('npm restart', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: why do you need to restart ?

Comment: I need to restart my script because I'm writing a script to get the new version of the code using `GIT` but the first step is to understand how to restart the script himself...

Answer (score 0):

If your Master process died, there is no way to reanimate him by himself.

Have a look at [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to restart your script.

Answer (score 0):

**Another option**: you can use `forever` npm module in order to start and monitor app.
So the restart function like this if from api:

```
app.get('/restart', function (req, res, next) {
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Or if you are using a cluster approach you can kill the child and fork new one as shown below [checkout cluster documentation for node,

```
cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
    logger.info('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died :(, starting another one.');
    cluster.fork();
});
```

Comment: Ok, on my Ubuntu server I tried PM2 but how to restart the process after executing `process.exit(1);` ?

Comment: I am not sure if pm2 supports restart functionality how you want hence i recommended forever, pm2 needs to be restarted externally as far i know. with pm2 you can look for signals and make sure your node restarts gracefully. Where as forever will restart your node as soon as it sees its down, so process.exit(1) will kill node and forever will start it again.

Comment: I tested with pm2 and pm2 does support restart functionality like forever. I killed the process using "/restart" and saw pm2 restart it, you can verify this by starting your app using pm2 and doing a **pm2 list** after each time you do a restart. you will notice that restart column will increment its value after every restart